# play and pause multiple html5 video, and blur it on pause

Tags: jquery, html, video

Yes, I'm trying to play and pause multiple Videos.

so if I play one I should pause the others one. The video itself Should be Blurred but not on play.
Hope makes sense?

http://jsfiddle.net/1frjov8e/

js:

```
$(function () {

 var filters = "blur(" + blur + ")";
$('.video-thumbnail').on('click', function () {
    // Just go ahead and pause/reset all the video elements
    $('video').each(function () {
        this.pause();
        this.currentTime = 0;
        $('video').css('-webkit-filter', filters);
    });

    $('#' + $(this).data('video-id')).get(0).play();
});





});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you'd like, if I understood correctly.

```
$('audio,video').bind('play', function() {
    activated = this;
    $('audio,video').each(function() {
        if(this != activated) this.pause();
    });
});
```

Basically just checking if this not the video we just clicked on, and pausing them.

Here's your updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1frjov8e/1/

---

Edited with request from the comments.  I think I've managed to effectively blur the other videos.
You can change the actual CSS to whatever you'd like. The css filter I used doesn't have wide support. Here's the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1frjov8e/14/

and relevant code:

JQuery:

```
$('audio,video').bind('play', function() {
    activated = this;
    $('audio,video').each(function() {
        var clickedVideo = $(this);
        if(this != activated){ 
            this.pause();
            clickedVideo.addClass('blurme');
        }
        else {
            clickedVideo.removeClass('blurme');
        }

    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.blurme {
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px) grayscale(.5) opacity(0.8);
}
```

Comment: thanks, does the job. Any idea how to blur it? perhaps with css? adding a class?

Comment: Yeah, you could just style a class and add it into the function. Maybe just an overlay?  Hmm... I've never tried to blur a video element. I'll try and see what I come up with.

Comment: should be something like this but doesn't work, could u please have a look?  http://jsfiddle.net/1frjov8e/3/

Comment: I've updated my answer above with (hopefully) working code for what you need. I would suggest editing the css class to your needs.